# KeyError: item not in index while trying to build boxplot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, indexing

I am trying to build a boxplot out of a simple dataframe. I take one with multiple columns and only take the two that I need:

```
mydata = data[['addr_state','loan_amnt']].dropna().copy()
mydata['loan_amnt'] = mydata['loan_amnt'].astype(float)
mydata[:5]

addr_state  loan_amnt
0   AZ  5,000.00
1   GA  2,500.00
2   IL  2,400.00
3   CA  10,000.00
4   OR  3,000.00

mydata.columns

Index(['addr_state', 'loan_amnt'], dtype='object')
```

Basically, it's a bunch of state - amount records and I am trying to build the candles for it:

```
mydata.boxplot(column='addr_state')

KeyError: "['addr_state'] not in index"
```

I tried set_index() and rebuild_index() but neither seem to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html), *column* argument should be the numeric value (input to a `groupby` not its arguments) to run the boxplot and *by* argument be the grouping variable:

```
mydata.boxplot(column='loan_amnt', by='addr_state')
```

To demonstrate with random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1212)
mydata = pd.DataFrame({'loan_amnt': np.random.randn(50)*100,
                       'tool': ["".join(np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia',
                                         'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],1)) for _ in range(50)]})

mydata.boxplot(column='loan_amnt', by='tool')
```

[image: Boxplot Output]