# ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

After running the code, this happens:

> ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible

I do not quite understand what is the error above

Honestly, pretty new to python, was referring to a code and following it to make a boxplot graph, but encountered an error, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


title = "Annual Bus Population"
titlelen = len(title)
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()

filename = 'annual-bus-population-by-passenger-capacity.csv'
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=["i4", "U50", "i8"], delimiter=",", names=True)

#print("Original data: " + str(data.shape))

null_rows = np.isnan(data['number'])
nonnull_values = data[null_rows==False]
#print("Filtered data: " + str(nonnull_values.shape))

labels = list(set(data['capacity']))
capacities = np.arange(0,len(labels))
capacity_number = data[['capacity','number']]

numbers = capacity_number['number']

values_nine = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '<10']
values_fifteen = numbers[capacity_number['capacity'] == '10-15']
values_twenty = numbers[capacity_number['capacity'] == '16-20']
values_twentyfive = numbers[capacity_number['capacity'] == '21-25']
values_thirty= numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '21-30']
values_thirtyfive = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '31-35']
values_fourty = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '36-40']
values_fourtyfive = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '40-45']
values_fifty = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '45-50']
values_fiftyfive = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '51-55']
values_sixty = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '56-60']
values_sixtyfive = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '61-65']
values_seventy = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '66-70']
values_moreseventy = numbers[capacity_number ['capacity'] == '>70']


values_total = [values_nine,values_fifteen,values_twenty,values_twentyfive,values_thirty,values_thirtyfive,values_fourty,values_fourtyfive,values_fifty,values_fiftyfive,values_sixty,values_sixtyfive,values_seventy,values_moreseventy]

#print(values_total.shape)
#print()

plt.figure(2, figsize=(30,30))
plt.title(title,fontsize=50)
plt.ylabel('Number of passengers',fontsize=40)
plt.yticks(fontsize=30)
plt.xticks(fontsize=30,rotation='vertical')
bp_dict = plt.boxplot(values_total,labels=labels,patch_artist=True)


## change outline color, fill color and linewidth of the boxes
for box in bp_dict['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set( color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)
    # change fill color
    box.set( facecolor = '#1b9e77' )

## change color and linewidth of the whiskers
for whisker in bp_dict['whiskers']:
    whisker.set(color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)

## change color and linewidth of the caps
for cap in bp_dict['caps']:
    cap.set(color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)

## change color and linewidth of the medians
for median in bp_dict['medians']:
    median.set(color='#b2df8a', linewidth=2)

## change the style of fliers and their fill
for flier in bp_dict['fliers']:
    flier.set(marker='D', color='#e7298a', alpha=0.5)

print(bp_dict.keys())

for line in bp_dict['medians']:
    # get position data for median line
    x, y = line.get_xydata()[1] # top of median line
    # overlay median value
    plt.text(x, y, '%.1f' % y,
         horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=30) # draw above, centered

fliers = []
for line in bp_dict['fliers']:
    ndarray = line.get_xydata()
    if (len(ndarray)>0):
       max_flier = ndarray[:,1].max()
       max_flier_index = ndarray[:,1].argmax()
       x = ndarray[max_flier_index,0]
       print("Flier: " + str(x) + "," + str(max_flier))

       plt.text(x,max_flier,'%.1f' % max_flier,horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=30,color='green') 

plt.show()
```

The error was in this line:

> bp_dict = plt.boxplot(values_total,labels=labels,patch_artist=True)

Dataset gotten from:

> https://data.gov.sg/dataset/annual-age-bus-population-by-passenger-capacity

Any help is greatly appreciated ^^
thanks

Comment: Hello Damian.   This is a long code example. For people to help, you need to state on which line the error occurred.  It would be better to just paste the whole traceback text you received with the error.  Thank you.

Comment: bp_dict = plt.boxplot(values_total,labels=labels,patch_artist=True) 
this was where the error was, sorry!

Comment: Its also polite to mention that dataset is available at https://data.gov.sg/dataset/annual-age-bus-population-by-passenger-capacity

Comment: So sorry about that, will include that right now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in your `labels` variable.  Specifically, you have extra values in it such as `15-Nov`.  Also, you lose the order of the labels when you use the `set()` function, so they come out in a random order.   I'm not quite sure what you need to do to fix it tonight, but you can just remove the `labels` parameter from your call to `plt.boxplot()` to get something working.  Then you can figure out labels that work.

The error is trying to say "The dimensions of the data and dimension of the labels do not match".

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**labels should be feature_names** (as is column dimension, or axis=1) in order to be drawn in one plot (matplot) by different column-divisions.
But your labels_var is just a list of one column (capacity) values - it is not correct.
You need either pivot_table your dataframe ... or [plt.boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544123/keyerror-item-not-in-index-while-trying-to-build-boxplot-with-pandas) (not ax.boxplot - I did't investigate why) gives an opportunity to use the grouping_param e.g. "by 'capacity'" (possibly suits your case)... or you can try to use [seaborn](https://aiaspirant.com/box-plot/) library - probably it gives more opportunities

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following for plotting for older versions.

```
bp_dict = plt.boxplot(values_total.transpose(),labels=labels,patch_artist=True)
```